# How to get OnPresence and OnRosterList to not be non-responsive

Tags: c#, agsxmpp

Currently, I am able to be connected to the server, and I was able to set my "status" and my presence. However, I am unable to get my "friends/buddies/contacts" to come up.

```
   xmpp = new XmppClientConnection();
   xmpp.ConnectServer = 
        xmpp.UseSSL = true;
        xmpp.Port = 5223;

        xmpp.Server = 
        xmpp.Resource = 
        xmpp.UseSSL = true;
        xmpp.Port = 5223;

        xmpp.Username = username;
        xmpp.Password = password;
        xmpp.SocketConnectionType = SocketConnectionType.Direct;
        xmpp.AutoRoster = true;
        xmpp.AutoPresence = true;
        xmpp.AutoResolveConnectServer = false;
        xmpp.AutoAgents = false;
        xmpp.RegisterAccount = false;
        xmpp.UseCompression = false;

        xmpp.OnReadXml += new XmlHandler(OnReadXml);
        xmpp.OnWriteXml += new XmlHandler(OnWriteXml);

        xmpp.OnStreamError += new XmppElementHandler(OnStreamError);
        xmpp.OnSocketError += new ErrorHandler(OnSocketError);
        xmpp.ClientSocket.OnValidateCertificate += new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ClientSocket_OnValidateCertificate);

        xmpp.OnIq += new IqHandler(OnIq);
        xmpp.OnRosterStart += new ObjectHandler(OnRosterStart);
        xmpp.OnRosterItem += new agsXMPP.XmppClientConnection.RosterHandler(OnRosterItem);
        xmpp.OnRosterEnd += new ObjectHandler(OnRosterEnd);

        xmpp.OnPresence += new PresenceHandler(OnPresence);
        xmpp.OnMessage += new MessageHandler(OnMessage);
        xmpp.OnError += new ErrorHandler(OnError);
        xmpp.OnLogin += new ObjectHandler(OnLogin);
        xmpp.OnAuthError += new XmppElementHandler(OnAuthError);
        xmpp.OnClose += new ObjectHandler(OnClose);
        xmpp.OnSaslStart += new agsXMPP.sasl.SaslEventHandler(OnSaslStart);

        try { xmpp.Open(); }
        catch {  }

        do { Thread.Sleep(300); }
        while (!xmpp.Authenticated);

        for (bool IsBinding = false; IsBinding == false; Thread.Sleep(1000))
           if (xmpp.XmppConnectionState.ToString().CompareTo("Binding") != 0)
               IsBinding = true;
```

And for my OnPresence and OnRosterList I have (unfortunately, none of the following works.):

```
    private void OnRosterStart(object sender)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Roster has started.");
    }

    private void OnRosterItem(object sender, agsXMPP.protocol.iq.roster.RosterItem item)
    {
        messenger.AddToRoster(item.Name);
        messenger.AddToRoster(item.Jid.User);
    }
    private void OnRosterEnd(object sender)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Roster has ended.");
    }

    private void OnPresence(object sender, Presence pres)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hello");
        Console.WriteLine("Here are your contacts: ");
        Console.WriteLine("{0}@{1}  {2}", pres.From.User, pres.From.Server, pres.Type);
    }
```

http://puu.sh/gr73T/a8595b59aa.png

Thanks.

Problem Statement: Initially, OnPresence doesn't do anything. (I understand it is an async function, however, it is clearly not working after keeping the application open for 30 minutes waiting.) Furthermore, I'd thought I heard somewhere that OnPresence should be handled once you send your presence to the server, however I am not getting my "contacts/friends/ buddies" presence at all.

Solution:
I have gotten this resolved. The solution is to not run any of these handlers in a thread. ;)

Comment: `OnPresence` and `OnRosterList`  are event handlers; they only get called if an event is fired.  If they're being unresponsive, it's because you put some code in them that makes them unresponsive.  That `MessageBox.Show` call is a prime suspect.

Comment: I have removed it on my IDE and recompiled. Doesn't change anything. :(

Comment: You mean "doesn't change anything about `OnPresence`'s behavior," right?  Please be more precise and specific  in your statements.  "It doesn't work" is not a problem statement.

Comment: Initially, OnPresence doesn't do anything. (I understand it is an async function, however, it is clearly not working after keeping the application open for 30 minutes waiting.) Furthermore, I'd thought I heard somewhere that OnPresence should be handled once you send your presence to the server, however I am not getting my "contacts/friends/ buddies" presence at all.

Comment: Does OnRosterStart fire?

Comment: Nope. It doesn't. The Puush Image is what my console window looks like.

Comment: Well, then you're not even getting out of the starting gate.

Comment: Yeah. If OnRosterStart was handled, I probably could have solved the problem myself. :)

Comment: What I'm saying is you can't drive the car if you don't start the engine.  Figure out why OnRosterStart is not firing, and you should be halfway there.